# prove this equation has at least two real solutions

Tags: analysis

I want to prove that $2^x=2-x^2$ has at least two real solutions. I am trying to use Bolzano theorem to prove this, that is if $f(x)=2^x-2+x^2$=$0$ then $f(x)$ is continuous on R will be negative somewhere and positive somewhere and so satisfy Bolzano theorem and there will be some real value that $f(c)=0$, but I don't know how to show or prove this equation has at least two real  solutions.

I appreciate anyone who show that for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try $x=0$, $x=1$, and $x=-2$ as inputs for $f$.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Well that is what I did after I Plotted the function in Maple and I noticed where is the function negative and where is positive, but I want to be more precisely and to get more precisely proof if it is possible ( I mean how to prove using the principals of analysis maybe?)

Comment: @user50382: Use the intermediate value theorem twice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ and $g$ by the functions such that $f(x)=2^x+x^2-2$ for $x \in [-2,0]$ and $g(x)=2^x+x^2-2$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Nos, apply Bolzano’s Theorem on both functions. This gives you (at least) to solutions to the equation.